# Firing different functionality on resize

Tags: jquery

I've tried googling this but I'm not entirely sure what keywords I should be using, so I'm coming up empty. In any case, I feel like I'm missing something relatively simple in my functions and the way they're firing.

My desired functionality is this: I have a little arrow next to my nav, with the structure ".menu-item-has-children a i". On mobile (below 880px), I want to click that `<i>` element and have it toggle the `<ul>` below. On desktop, I don't. That works just fine until I'm switching between those two viewport sizes (below 880 and above 880). Then the desired functionality won't fire until I reload the page. My jQuery looks like this:

```
jQuery(document.ready(function($) {
   function mobileNav() {
       var w = $(window).width(); 

       if (w < 879) {
           $('.menu-item-has-children a i').click(function(e) {
               e.preventDefault();
               $(this).parents('menu-item-has-children').children('ul').toggle();
               $(this).toggleClass('turned');
           });
       }
   }

    mobileNav();

    jQuery(window).resize(function($) {
        mobileNav();
    });
});
```

Comment: Im wondering if your backend is producing different markup for mobile vs. desktop. Check to see if `$('.menu-item-has-children a i')` is there for both.

Comment: Thanks shanimal - I checked, and yes, it's the same markup for both. My jQuery, as far as I'm aware, isn't altering the markup for any of the elements - the intent is only to modify the behavior of said elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im not exactly sure but I think the reason it wasn't working is because there is no `.` in front of `menu-item-has-children` in the line with `$(this).parents('menu-item-has-children').children('ul').toggle();`

fwiw, you can use the delegate syntax of the click handler which eliminates the need for domReady and eliminate the resize function, because we don't actually run any behavior when the screen is resized. We only care what happens when `.menu-item-has-children a i` nodes are clicked. So we can check the screen size on each click.

```
   jQuery(document).on('click', '.menu-item-has-children a i', function(e) {
       var $ = jQuery;
       var $this = $(this);
       e.preventDefault();
       if (879 < $(window).width()) {
           $this.parents('.menu-item-has-children').children('ul').toggle();
           $this.toggleClass('turned');
       }
   });
```

Comment: thanks a lot! That seems to work really well. The only thing that I'm not getting - and maybe this is beyond the point of this post - is that the point of this function I wrote is to make visibility on click on mobile (as this is doing), but to use CSS hover to make the subnav visible on desktop.

Comment: whoops...I hit "enter" too early. So the problem is that the toggle function toggles display:block and display:none inline, which overrides my :hover request in my CSS file. Any advice there? Thanks again.

Comment: PPS - the missing "." was just a typo in transferring it over into StackOverflow; in my actual code, it's where it's supposed to be.

Comment: haha, as soon as I was about to report that I'd figured it out, I saw that you posted. Essentially, this is how I just solved it: instead of using .toggle(), I substituted .toggleClass() for all visibility-related issues. Then I was able to tie all of my visibilities into CSS without having to worry about the inline "display: block" and "display: none" that .toggle() creates.

Comment: Thanks again for your help, @shanimal ! That was really useful to me.